# Rails - when to use .reload in code / idiomatic Ruby/Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I've often heard using `.reload` is common in testing Rails applications, but what about in the actual app code?

The code below works, but I've been trying to think if using `.reload` is a little crude here. Especially since the kind of operations I'm doing (adding to a `has_many` relationship via helper method `add_passenger`, calling `rotate!`) seem pretty typical.

Is this use of `.reload` okay? Or is there a better way to structure my code?

```rb
    def organize
      Driver.find_each(&:clear_space)

      untaken = Rider.unassigned
      open_drivers = Driver.available

      # assume enough seats for all riders
      while untaken.reload.size > 0
        cur = untaken.first

        open_drivers.reload.each do |driver|
          if cur.prefers_strongest?(driver: driver)
            driver.add_passenger(rider: cur)
          end
        end

        untaken.rotate! if cur.car.nil?
      end

      Car.all
    end
```

```rb
class Driver < Person
  has_one :car, inverse_of: :driver, dependent: :destroy
  delegate :riders, :riders_count, :clear_space, to: :car

  after_create :create_car!

  scope :available, -> { joins(:car).where('riders_count < ?', :total_space) }

  def clear_space
    riders.delete_all if riders_count > 0
  end

  def add_passenger(rider:)
    riders << rider if car.has_space?
  end

  def remove_passenger(rider:) 
    riders.delete(rider) if riders.exists?(rider.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: `reload` will make a database query and update object with received values. Possible race conditions can be solved without "reload", but it is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Using `reload` seems kind of heavy-handed here. I suppose it's fine if you really want to re-run the query each time (though I didn't even realize you could use `reload` to re-run a query on a collection, so possibly it's not the most easily understandable?). But, if your `untaken` list will never grow larger, it would be better performce to treat it like a normal list, and remove elements as needed with Enumerable / Array methods, rather than re-running the query

Comment: Yeah @maxpleaner I agree. If I do convert the `untaken` and `open_driver` scope calls (which returns a relation I believe?) to arrays via `.to_a`, I'd lose the bi-directional ability though correct? And then I'd have to manually add another line to say remove from the array of `untaken` riders once one of the riders in it is added to a driver?

Answer (score 1):

`#reload` is really just used to "refresh" or "rehdrydate" a record or a set of records by performing a select query. As such its really hard to authoritively say a indiomatic user as its really just a generic tool that can be used when having a up-to-the-second representation of the db data is needed.

But the answer to *is there a better way to structure my code?* Is almost certainly yes. The amount of data shuffling in and out of the database here to simply arrange passangers in a car suggests the data modeling is off or that you should consider a simpler solution wher you arrange first and then persist the data once instead of a loop.

Comment: Ah I see! Makes sense. Do you know where I can find more information on a possible simpler solution (eg. arranging data "off the DB", then persisting it into the DB after all the arranging/assigning is done)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to call `reload` on a top-level scope. Those calls aren't cached. What *is* cached are those calls made via an ActiveRecord instance.

In that case you can use `reload` to ditch the cache, either on the whole record, or just on the associated records, like `@user.rides.reload`.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. Rails does cache SQL calls such as those made by a "top level scope" - it caches the actual raw DB response so that when you generate the same query it uses the canned response. What you are correct in is that `reload` does not avoid that cache - `uncached` does. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching

Comment: Its also more helpful to use the term re-hydrating when explaining what `.reload` does. It refreshes the in memory representation by creating a select query and sets any instance variables of the object from the result. I wouldn't really refer to this as a cache as the object is not really intended to cache the data across requests.

Comment: Would your intended action be then to remove all the `.reload` calls? If I do that, then the loop seems to run infinitely (eg. adding a rider to a driver does not seem to update the `untaken` riders list). Should I not be querying/using active records like this?

Comment: @max That's interesting, and something I'd never realized, if only because it's never been an issue for me. The caching at the model level has been problematic in the past because of introducing new records in the mix. Do you want to create your own answer? That might be better.

Comment: TIL what calling `#reload` on a relation does. Its like calling `.map(&:reload)` except it reloads all the records with a single SQL query. https://gist.github.com/maxcal/cbf1dc961f2a22506b011d29a27842cc