# Rails - Memoize an ActiveRecord and some eager-loaded associations for an expensive calculation, then resave as records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a question about [caching db records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65569125/3357635) for a simple update operation that can have side-effects on many associated records.

Because this action is currently coded procedurally, the side effects cause multiple db reloads, as the transactions are committed one by one. It's very slow.

I'm wondering if there's a Rails-y way to cache the main record and the eager-loaded associations on a temporary object that has all the properties of the nested records, and do all the computations on that object until all side effects have been computed. Then, update the changed records on the different tables once, when everything's done.

Basically I'm trying to quarantine the computation methods so they don't keep reloading the updated records from the db. Something like you might do for user-entered form data.

Am I overthinking this? Do i just want a PORO here? An ActiveModel object?

#### Specifics

Let's say i have an "article-editing" collaboration app, each `Article` has a `User`-votable `Title`.

Every `Article` view shows a table of proposed `Titles` and their `Votes`. We have a UI where users can create and propose a new `Title` for the current `Article`, or create a `Vote` on someone else's `Title`. The vote can have 5 possible values.

The UI has two possible types of CRUD operations then:

- `Title` create/update "Propose a title"
- `Title.Vote` create/update "Vote on this title"

The title of the article is decided by totalling the votes, and weighting them by user reputation.

So both the Title and Vote CRUD operations initiate a series of expensive computations, where the reputation of the proposing or voting `User` is weighed, together with the vote value, against the votes and reputations of all other voters on the current post. It's also weighed against the `User`'s own votes on other `Titles`.

In other words, it's a complicated computation that happens on what is otherwise a simple CRUD operation. It has several side-effects.

The end result of the CRUD will be a multi-table `update` operation for the side-effects on various associations, followed by a re-render of the table of proposed Titles (and their votes).

Potential side effects: The `updates` may create a new `Title` with a starting `Vote`, change the `Vote.value` of another `title.vote`, and if the user's reputation is high enough, may potentially update the current `Article.title` itself.

Currently this is being done procedurally, one step after the other, with many `reload`s of model records as they are changed. Obviously, it's really slow.

I'm wondering if there's a more Rails-y way to

- eager load the Post including its Titles, Votes, and the Users of all these associations, and
- instantiate a sort of "working object" that we could do the computation on, preventing all the reloads.

At the end of the computation, the records would be saved if altered, and a newly eager-loaded `Article` record with its associations would be sent to be rendered as a fresh Article Title Votes table.

It seems like a [non-ActiveRecord model](https://code.tutsplus.com/non-activerecord-models-in-rails-4--cms-25452t), an `ActiveModel`, is the way to go here. But I can't imagine how to initialize such an object or objects (sending the Article and its many nested eager-loaded associations, I imagine), so that the object has access to each and every current and future attribute of each of the associated AR records, without being able to affect the records themselves.

Basically i'm imagining a "scratchpad" version of the Article and associated Titles and Title.votes.users that I can use to calculate the eventual result, without initiating further reloads, etc.

Comment: Maybe what you are referring to is the N+1 queries problem. If this is correct, Rails has its own built-in method inside ActiveRecord, called `includes`, to let associations to be eager-loaded. But its better to read the documentation first before using this, you can refer to this: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.2/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes (additional explanation: https://engineering.gusto.com/a-visual-guide-to-using-includes-in-rails/)